# stmt bind_result() doesn't bind all columns

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I've got a simple query that I'm trying to bind to three variables in a fetch loop. Unfortunately, it picks up the first two columns and leaves the 3rd as an empty string... I'm at a loss... any ideas?

```
 $db = new mysqli("host.com", "username", "password", "db_name");

 $q = "SELECT user_id, meta_key, meta_value FROM wp_usermeta WHERE (meta_key='first_name' OR meta_key='last_name') AND meta_value != '';";
 $stmt = $db->prepare($q);
 $stmt->execute();
 $stmt->bind_result($col1,$col2,$col3);
 while ( $stmt->fetch() ) {
      echo $col1." - ".$col2." - ".$col3."<br />";
      }
```

Output:

```
 2 - first_name - 
 2 - last_name - 
 5 - last_name - 
 5 - first_name - 
 6 - first_name - 
 6 - last_name - 
 8 - last_name - 
 8 - first_name - 
 9 - first_name - 
 9 - last_name -
```

Comment: Did you check if they actually have meta values? If they're `sql null`, then `meta_value != ''` would let that through, since null can't be equal to anything, including itself.

Comment: Could `meta_value` be NULL?

Comment: I've checked - I ran the exact same query in phpmyadmin and it returned all of the data perfectly - they are definitely not NULL in the database.

Comment: Can you do `var_dump($col1, $col2, $col3)`?

Comment: Do you get the same result with `AND meta_value > ''`? (checks both for empty strings and NULL values)

Comment: Okay, when I do var_dump on them, I get $col1 is an integer (2,5, n), $col2 is a string ("last_name" or "first_name") and $col3 is always an empty string. So strange...

Comment: jeroen - yes, I tried that with the same result, also tried "AND (meta_value != '' AND meta_value IS NOT NULL)" with the same result.

Comment: The AND meta_value != '' part is just there for clarity actually. The data I'm working with is all clean and there are no blank values, but I put it there to prove that the empty results on the meta_value column wasn't being caused by bad data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally figured this out. The meta_value field is a *longtext* data type. Apparently, if you try to bind a longtext field before using store_result, PHP returns an empty string without giving any sort of error or warning to that effect.

Here is the working code:

```
 $db = new mysqli("host.com", "username", "password", "db_name");

 $q = "SELECT user_id, meta_key, meta_value FROM wp_usermeta WHERE (meta_key='first_name' OR meta_key='last_name') AND meta_value != '';";
 $stmt = $db->prepare($q);
 $stmt->execute();
 $stmt->store_result();
 $stmt->bind_result($col1,$col2,$col3);
 while ( $stmt->fetch() ) {
      echo $col1." - ".$col2." - ".$col3."<br />";
      }
```